# EditText-backed TextField in Compose

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-jetpack-compose, interop, android-view

I want to implement [Image keyboard support](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/image-keyboard) into a Compose app. As [this two-year-old issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198323023) shows, there are currently no public APIs to achieve it.

Although `TextInputServiceAndroid` class has a `fun createInputConnection(outAttrs: EditorInfo): InputConnection`, it is marked as `internal`, and is buried so deep inside the framework that overriding it by any means is a death sentence, so my only option is to use View-Compose interop.

Any notion of advanced operation of Views has vanished from my head over the years, and even a monumental task of changing `EditText` colors or shapes eludes me as if I've just opened Android Studio for the first time.

So I want to ask the community - what is the most painless way to back a `TextField` with a `View` that supports overriding `onCreateInputConnection` and is easy to respect compose `Theme` with?

I've tried it with good ol' `EditText` like this:

```kotlin
val textColor = LocalContentColor.current.toArgb()

AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    factory = {
        object : EditText(it) {
            override fun onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo: EditorInfo): InputConnection {
                val ic: InputConnection = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo)
                EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, arrayOf("image/*"))
                val callback =
                    InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener { inputContentInfo, flags, opts ->
                        val lacksPermission = (flags and
                                InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1 && lacksPermission) {
                            try {
                                inputContentInfo.requestPermission()
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                return@OnCommitContentListener false
                            }
                        }
                        uris.add(inputContentInfo.contentUri)
                        true
                    }
                return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback)
            }
        }.apply {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            setTextColor(textColor)
        }
    }
)
```

But customizing this `EditText` further is kinda non-trivial, which is shown right here on StackOverflow with hundreds of questions of the same "How do I change EditText ***your_component_here*** color?" flavor with tens of answers each.

I would rather not maintain two theming systems simultaneously but fetch required values from `MaterialTheme`. What is the current go-to text editing view in Android Views which would allow for such customizations?